# How to Create a Separate Clock and control it with Custom control in Cesium Js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cesiumjs

I'm working in a simulation project where I need to apply animations on different entities. Project demanding is to create custom control to Play/Pause animations. Entities are using Interpolated Paths to move on them. As shown in this [example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Interpolation.html).

I want to apply a separate Clock rather then using default **viewer.clock**. Hence I've tried to modified the above example. Here is the [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

I've created a separate clock as:

```
var start = Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(new Date(2015, 2, 25, 16));
var stop = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(
  start,
  360,
  new Cesium.JulianDate()
);

//Make sure viewer is at the desired time.
var clock = new Cesium.Clock();
clock.startTime = start.clone();
clock.stopTime = stop.clone();
clock.currentTime = start.clone();
clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;
clock.multiplier = 10;
clock.shouldAnimate = true;
var clockViewModel = new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock);
var viewModel = new Cesium.AnimationViewModel(clockViewModel);
```

and tried to calling them like:

```
Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Start", function () {
  viewModel.pauseViewModel.command();
});

Sandcastle.addDefaultToolbarButton("Stop", function () {
  viewModel.pauseViewModel.command();
});
```

But animation is not starting. Also not getting any exception. Please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why didn't the animation start?**

Note that the animation is performed with the clock of viewer in CesiumJS.
In your code viewer 's clock is different from your custom clock.
I mean viewer 's clock 's year is 2021 and your clock's year 2015.
So the availability of your entity(Cesium_Air.glb) will be false and finally, ModelVisualizer skips the rendering of your entity.

**Solution**
You should synchronize the clock of the viewer with your custom clock so that the availability of your entity becomes true.

Here is a [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).
Here is a [source code](https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJsSamples/blob/master/Animation/index.html).

Comment: Here it is. Thank you so much for the example code and a nice explanation.

Comment: could you please try to answer my another question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363812/trim-interpolated-polyline-where-terrain-is-intersecting-in-cesium)