# Trim interpolated polyline where terrain is intersecting in Cesium

Tags: javascript, canvas, cesiumjs

I'm trying to create an arc which will stop when it intersects terrain. Two variables **arc1** and **arc2** where **arc1** is without terrain intersection and **arc2** is with terrain intersection.

**arc1** is working properly but **arc2** is not stopping where it intersects the terrain.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  infoBox: false, //Disable InfoBox widget
  selectionIndicator: false, //Disable selection indicator
  shouldAnimate: true, // Enable animations
  terrainProvider: Cesium.createWorldTerrain(),
});

//Enable lighting based on the sun position
viewer.scene.globe.enableLighting = true;

//Enable depth testing so things behind the terrain disappear.
viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

// Cartesian3: start, mid and end points for polyline
var controls = [{x:-1942111.383043348,y:-4780646.881480431,z:3737538.9114379627},
                {x:-1847333.0834675943,y:-5281519.814050422,z:3579120.5547780637},
                {x:-1611854.2607850158,y:-5380130.367796415,z:3146339.4631628506}];


// Applying interpolation
var spline = Cesium.HermiteSpline.createNaturalCubic({
        times: [0.0, 0.5, 1],
        points: controls,
    });

var ppos = []; //Interpolated polyline cordinates
for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    var cartesian3 = spline.evaluate(i / 50);
    ppos.push(cartesian3);
}

/* Terrain and Polyline Intersection Detection */
var cartographic = [];
var cartographic_real = [];
ppos.forEach(p => {
    let dh = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(p);
    dh.height = 0;
    cartographic.push(dh);
    cartographic_real.push(Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(p));
});

// collecting actual terrain heights
Cesium.sampleTerrainMostDetailed(viewer.terrainProvider, cartographic).then((raisedPositionsCartograhpic) => {
    var t = true;
    var rpos = []; // 
    cartographic_real.forEach((p, i) => {
        if(t) rpos.push(ppos[i]);
        // If terrain height is more than polyline cordinate height
        if (i > 0 && t && (raisedPositionsCartograhpic[i].height - p.height)) {
          t = false;
          
          console.log("Stopped at:", p.height);
          console.log(rpos);
          drawNewArc(rpos);

        }
    });
});

/* --- */

function drawNewArc(rpos)
{
  var arc1 = {};
  arc1.polyline = { // Actual line without terrain intersection
          positions: ppos,
          width: 3,
          material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
      }
  
  var arc2 = {};
  arc2.polyline = { // This should stop where it intersects terrain
          positions: rpos,
          width: 3,
          material: Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(1.0),
      }
  
  var entity = viewer.entities.add(arc1);
  var entity2 = viewer.entities.add(arc2);
}

viewer.camera.flyTo({destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-112.081,36.097,10000)});
```

I want the Green polyline to stop when it hits any terrain.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJsHQ.jpg)

*I think I need to get and match all the points of the arc. I don't know how to get all the points of the Green arc.*

Here is the complete code [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) in sandcastle:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Success after repairing various mistakes in the code like:

Polyline segmentation was incorrect:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
```

Height matching condition was not correct:

```
if (i > 0 && t && (raisedPositionsCartograhpic[i].height - p.height)) {
```

Here is the complete working code [link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) . It can also have mistakes and there must be a better solution to achieve the objective. If someone has any better and fast solution, please kindly post here.